# change label text through drag and drop

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

http://comparebuilder.co.nf/formbuilder.php?xlsx=webfeed.xlsx

A bootstrap formbuilder is used and an excel sheet is imported to generate tags in the slider. Now the tag must be dragged over an input label and the label text must be replaced with the tag text. i have used jquery ui draggable and droppable.

```
 $("#tagcloud .tag").draggable({
     appendTo: "body",
     helper: "clone"
 });

 $(".control-group .control-label").droppable({
     activeClass: "ui-state-default",
     hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
     accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
     drop: function (event, ui) {
         $(this).empty();
         $("<span></span>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
     }
 });
```

i can drag the tag from the slider but even after dropping it over the tag the text doesn't change. what is wrong with it ?

Comment: hi, i am sorry the bootstrap form builder(https://github.com/minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder) has a lot of dependencies and it won't run on jsfiddle. this is what is need to do http://jsfiddle.net/PLWcV/3/  but the same isn't working

Comment: It works fine for me... i dragged the items into the label of input and it's text changed accordingly.